# Версионирование javaScript приложения

Tags: git, reactjs, npm, контроль-версий, версионирование

Возникла необходимость одновременно поддерживать и разрабатывать несколько версий одного проекта, некоторые фичи должны быть общими для версий, другие же уникальные.

Простое ветвление в гите, начинает превращаться в ад.  Приложение написано на реакт, первая мысль поделить приложение на модули и прописывать в package.json версии специфичные для данного инстанса. Был ли у кого-нибудь похожий опыт и как это решали?

Answer (score 1):

Можно выделить некое ядро и хранить его в отдельном репозитории. 
Под новые версии создавать новые репозитории и подключать к ним ядро через git submodule - https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8

Answer (score 1):

Я только хотел добавить что для разработки удобно использовать фишку npm - поддержка работы с гит на уровне dependencies, вот что я имею в виду:

> package.json

```js
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "tiny-sdf": "git+https://github.com/strangerintheq/tiny-sdf.git#1.1.9",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

так я позависел от либы `tiny-sdf`, от коммита с тегом `1.1.9`, можно указывать имя ветки или хэш коммита.